# Why is my configuration file being checked in despite my .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

My .gitignore has the following:

```
./config.json
```

But my config.json is still being committed when I make changes.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of your folder structure

Comment: Was the file added to git before you added it to gitignore?

Comment: Yes, the file was added to git before adding it to .gitignore. The file is in the base directory of the repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you file was added to repository before you added it to gitignore you should explicity remove it from repository

```
git rm config.json
git commit <message>
```

After removed from repository this file will be ignore as expected.

If you want to save this file in your file system you can remove with [--cached](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#git-rm---cached) option

```
git rm --cached config.json
```